# creating an exception while opening a directory

Tags: python, exception

I encountered a problem while opening a directory. I loop over all directories and I walk in:

```
for i in var1:
        for j in var2:
                if i == j: continue
                      sdir = i+'_'+j
                      os.chdir("/home/Documents/test"+sdir)
```

Everything works fine as long as there is a directory according to the name `sdir`. When it doesn't exist, the following error is thrown:

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /home/Documents/test/a_b

However I have a directory named `b_a`. Therefore I want to swap `i` and `j` in my code. I mean if there is no `a_b` directory -> swap `a` and `b` -> go in the `b_a` directory.

How may I do an exception using `os.chdir("/home/Documents/test/"+sdir)`?

Comment: Put it in try except block. And swap in except block. And use yet another try except block in except block to handle if even that fails.

Comment: @monica please use PEP8 for formatting your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would recommend using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to create the folder structure:

```
import os

base = os.path.join('/home', 'Documents', 'test')
```

and then just [`try`](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) it:

```
try:
     os.chdir(os.path.join(base, i+'_'+j))
except OSError:
     try:
         os.chdir(os.path.join(base, j+'_'+i))
     except OSError:
         print('total fail', i, j)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    os.chdir("/home/Documents/test"+sdir) 
except OSError:
    #your desired behaviour when the try block fails
```